# Correspondence of the symplectic structure induced by a Lagrangian on TM and the canonical symplectic structure on T*M

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics, pullback

I am trying to prove in a coordinate-independent way (see Fecko's "Differential Geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists, problem (18.3.2)) that

$$\theta_L := S(dL) = \hat{L}^* \theta \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where $\theta_L$ is the Cartan 1-form on $\pi:TM \to M$ associated to the Lagrangian function  $L:TM \to \Bbb R$;  $S :=\hat{1}^\uparrow$ is the vertical endomorphism (vertical lift of the ${1 \choose 1}$ unit tensor field on $M$), $\theta$ is the canonical 1-form on $\tau:T^*M \to M$ and $\hat{L}^* \theta$ is the pullback of $\theta$ induced by the the Legendre map $\hat L:TM \to T^*M$, defined by the relations ($v,w\in\pi^{-1}(x)$, $x \in M$):
$$\tau \circ\hat L = \pi \qquad \langle \hat L(v),w  \rangle :=w_v^\uparrow L \equiv \left.\frac{d}{dt} \right|_0 L(v+tw)$$
I understand that
$$ \langle(\hat L^* \theta)_v,w  \rangle= \langle \theta_{\hat L(v)}, \hat L_*w  \rangle = \langle \hat L(v), \tau_* \hat L_*w  \rangle= \langle \hat L(v), \pi_*w  \rangle = \left(  \pi_*w  \right)^\uparrow L = \left.\frac{d}{dt} \right|_0 L(v+ t\pi_* w)$$

but cannot go on unless by using local canonical coordinates. Any hints?

Comment: I'm not used to the notations you employ, but I suspect that compared to the notations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tangent_bundle#Canonical_tensor_fields_on_the_tangent_bundle), $w_v^{\uparrow} = \mathrm{vl}_v(w)$ and $S$ is (the adjoint of) the canonical endomorphism $J$. Then for $w \in T_v(TM)$, $$\langle (\theta_L)_v, w \rangle = \langle S_v(dL_v), w \rangle = \langle dL_v, J_v w \rangle = \langle dL_v, (\pi_{\ast}w)^{\uparrow}_v \rangle = (\pi_{\ast}w)^{\uparrow}_v L.$$

Comment: Thank you, @JordanPayette, I think this solves my problem.